# How to Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in Adobe Animate CC 2019 While Publishing Apk

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6, animate-cc

While I am in the final step to upload my app. My App Giving two Problems.

**First Problem**

> "Error This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit
>   requirement
>
> The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but
>   they only have 32-bit native code: 2000001.
>
> Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App
>   Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device
>   architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids
>   increasing the overall size of your app. Learn More"

**Second Problem**

> Unoptimized APK Warning:
>
> This APK results in unused code and resources being sent to users.
>   Your app could be smaller if you used the Android App Bundle. By not
>   optimizing your app for device configurations, your app is larger to
>   download and install on users' devices than it needs to be. Larger
>   apps see lower install success rates and take up storage on users'
>   devices.
>
> Resolution:
>
> Use the Android App Bundle to automatically optimize for device
>   configurations, or manage it yourself with multiple APKs.

See I am trying to publish my app with new [SDK version 32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2Pyr.png)

I also read this [article.](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit) This is the latest problem. Please, Solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use AIR 33 to generate an Android 64bit APK. AIR 32 does not support this and will only produce a 32bit APK.

Currently you will need to create separate binaries for 64bit and 32bit and submit them if you plan to continue supporting older 32bit devices.

In order to get access to AIR 33 you will need to contact Harman directly via adobe.support@harman.com, as they are still in process of setting up a website to access the SDK.

---

Update: Harman have a site available to download AIR 33+ now

https://airsdk.harman.com

Comment: Thanks, For Great Way. Do I have buy Air 33 I can't find a free link?

Comment: Hi, You need to contact harman and accept their license. There is a free tier depends on your income now though similar to unity's model.

Comment: See My [New Air 33] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LCKt9bjdrP-UU81lncE-iGtDfJgO14lE/view?usp=sharing) and my [XML file] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rJsK6hWoI1igdRyc2Ij_Io2hdb1QPWa6/view?usp=sharing)

**But Same Problem that Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app.**

Comment: Currently you need to deliver 2 APKs to Google, one 64bit APK and one 32bit APK. You cannot package both versions with AIR 33. You need to specify the platform when packaging.

Comment: Thanks Here Is Solution https://actionscript-hindi.blogspot.com/2019/09/how-to-include-64-bit-and-32-bit-native.html?m=1